# UPnP Implementation

Tags: xml, sockets, http, soap, upnp

I am implementing UPnP AV control point. With UDP socket, I am able to discover the devices. From the url I am able to get the device and service descriptions of the server. 
Now, how do I implement SOAP? Can I implement it using the same UDP socket?
I am restricted to use ubuntu and c. I have the control url to which I need to send the request. i also have the url which contains the service description in XML. 
My main question is, how can I send a service url containing XML to the control url using HTTP post?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: UPnP control protocol is SOAP on HTTP over TCP, so a UDP socket won't work. The last question is essentially "how do I send a http request" which is a little vague -- have you tried anything? I suggest looking at [UPnP Device Architecture 2.0](http://upnp.org/specs/arch/UPnP-arch-DeviceArchitecture-v2.0.pdf) (part 3) for the details on what the request must contain.

Comment: i am trying to implement SOAP using curl command.

Comment: suppose i have the service actions in a url and i need to send the actions to the control url. how do i use curl command to get response from control url?